# What is the practical use of FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE of SQL Server 2012 (Code name: Denali) CTP 3

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

With Denali's CTP 3 release , we have more analytical functions out of which I am interested in two:

a) [First_Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)
b) [Last_Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231517%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

I understood that `FIRST_VALUE` returns first value based on partition and order by clause while `Last_Value` returns last value based on partition and order by clause.

But in what practical situation they will be useful? A sample real time situation will help me understand this.

Comment: Also see this SSC article that just came out http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlservernotesfromthefield/archive/2011/8/30/t_2D00_sql-enhancements_3A00_-first_5F00_value_28002900_-and-last_5F00_value_28002900_.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These functions can help you get other information from the resultset without using complicated self-joins, derived tables, etc. For example, let's say you have twenty forum messages in a table, and you want to know who started the thread, and who posted the last response. They are ordered by date/time, so while MIN() & MAX() can help you identify *when* the first & last posts occurred, they can't tell you who those authors were unless you went out and got that additional information somehow. Even that can be complicated - if you don't have a natural or artificial key column for example (you could join on an identity column), you might be tempted to join on the date/time values, which are not guaranteed to be unique...

Comment: +1 - It's basically shorthand for something that's much more complicated to do without the built-in function.